# Index Data in ElasticSearch using Apache Spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, etl

I am new in ElasticSearch. I have a huge data to index in Elasticsearch. I would like to use Apache Spark to index the data in Elasticsearch. Is it possible to do in ApacheSpark with better perfomance? If so can anyone help me out to do the indexing using ApacheSpark.

Comment: Yes, you can do so, though, I suggest you go through the official documentation first: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html

Comment: @Val Is there any fine Docs to read and get more about indexing using Spark especially in Java